# SharePoint 2016 - How to archive the my unused sub-sites

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sub-site

I've a SharePoint 2016 Farm, in a Site-collection I do have many sub sites, which are currently not in use. So i want to Archive them to reduce the space.

**what is best way to archive the sub sites ?**, I'd like to save them as a single file and whenever we need them, we will extract it and work with them.

Note that the sub sites has unique permissions, and has lot of documents and custom pages. Hence their size exceeds 50MB. **so we want a better solution than saving the site as a template.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to save unique permissions, per my knowledge you will need to use some 3rd party tools. Export-SPWeb does not contain unique permissions neither.

Comment: is there any other way to archive, if don't need unique permission to be saved

Comment: @JeganBaskaran, you can try export-spweb to export the site and import it when you need. A tutorial is here:https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/09/export-import-subsite-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html

Comment: thank you so much for sharing the solution, after importing the site, will it have the same name or the name which i given while exporting. and How to navigate to the newly imported site, Since I'm unable to find the site under the subsites where i'd imported